# mutt: select top message on startup

Tags: mutt

Currently, when I start mutt, it selects the top unread message in the index.

How can I configure mutt to select the top message (read or unread) on startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to the end of your `.muttrc` configuration file:

```
push <first-entry>
```

`first-entry` is the function called when you press <kbd>Home</kbd>, which takes you to the first message shown in your mailbox.

`push` will add this function as a keyboard entry.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.  I placed `exec first-entry` at the bottom of my `.muttrc`, which is functionally equivalent to `push <first-entry>` according to this: [http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-3.html#ss3.20](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-3.html#ss3.20).